# Can "keep clear of sb/sth" and "keep sb/sth away from sb/sth" be interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am wondering whether "**keep clear of** sb./sth.;" and "**keep** (sb./sth.) **away** (**from** sb./sth.)" can be interchangeable.

Do the following sentences have the same meaning?

Please keep clear of the barking dog.

Please keep (yourself) away (from the barking dog.)

Comment: Essentially the same. [*clear*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=clear): "*adv.* 2. Out of the way; completely away: *stood clear of the doors*.

Answer (score 4):

It is unusual to see either used reflexively (*Keep **yourself** {clear of/away from} the dog*) in contexts where actual physical separation is involved; we tend to simply delete the object whenever it's the same as the subject:

> Keep your child clear of the dog *and* Keep your child away from the dog *but*
>   Keep clear of the dog *and* Keep away from the dog.

*Away from* suggests stronger separation than *clear of*: *away from* is "Don't go anywhere near the dog" or "Avoid the dog's presence entirely", but *clear of* is "Don't go too near the dog".

And since *clear* is only metaphorically equivalent to "at a physical distance", it is more likely to be used in contexts where the distance itself is metaphorical:

> Keep clear of involvement with those people.

In fact, *clear* with a reflexive object is acceptable in contexts where *clear of* has a sense of *free of* rather than *at a distance from*.

> He was at some pains to keep himself clear of implication in the activities of his former mob friends.

Comment: What about "...to keep clear of the activities of his former mob friends"? :)

Comment: @KinzleB That's fine, but *away from* would be OK there, too--it implies "at a distance", physical or figurative. But *Keep **himself** clear of the activities* feels klunky to me.

Comment: I like your recent edits; a military usage "all clear" rings the bell. :)